help with internet access of ubuntu server 22.04.5 LTS
where I work, everyone has a login username and password for wifi authentication. in other words, after connecting to the wifi, a web page pops up and we need to login using our usernames and passwords. since I'm new with ubuntu server, I can only use netplan to connect to the wifi and don't know how to handle the login!
I'd be super thankful if anyone can help me with this issue
